# Why need Torbirdy when Thunderbird supports SOCKS proxy and Remote DNS

Tags: torbirdy

I read about torbirdy addon for Thunderbird, but it's still in Beta.

But I read, found out how to setup setup SOCKS proxy in Thunderbird, and enable remote DNS resolution to avoid DNS leaks, why exactly do I need Torbirdy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TorBirdy does not simply set proxy settings in Thunderbird, but does quite a few [changes](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/torbirdy/changes). Some additional things which the plugin does are:

- set the timezone to UTC (prevents revealing your timezone)
- disable IMAP `IDLE` command
- use a hidden service as keyserver for GnuPG

So in general TorBirdy tries to save you from attacks against your privacy/anonymity. Have a look at the [design goals](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/attachment/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/EMail/Thunderbird/Thunderbird+Tor.pdf). This documents describes it more in detail.